# How do I solve this differential equation $y''^2-2y'y''+3=0$ in parametric form?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I do have quite no idea about this one.
The obvious substitution $y'=p, y''=p\frac{dp}{dy}$ doesn't make the situation any better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

The equation being $$\Big(\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\Big)^2-\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+3=0$$ use $$p=\frac{dy}{dx}$$ and obtain $$\Big(\frac{dp}{dx}\Big)^2-p\frac{dp}{dx}+3=0$$ Consider it as a quadratic in $\frac{dp}{dx}$; solve it and it becomes separable since $$\frac{dp}{dx}=p\pm\sqrt{p^2-3}$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $2y'y'' = ((y')^2)'$

Then let $g = y'$ so the equation reformulates to:
$$(g')^2 - g^2 + 3 =0 $$ which is much simpler an easier to solve. Then find a solution for $g = g(x) = y' $ and integrate to find $y(x) $

Comment: Made an edit! My internet connection was broke

Answer (score 0):

Let $z=y'$, then $$\frac{dz}{dx}=z\pm\sqrt{z^2-3}\\ \frac{dx}{dz}=\frac{z\pm\sqrt{z^2-3}}3$$
then solve $x$ as a function of $z$
Sadly, the final integral, to get $y$ as a function of $x$, looks difficult.